# ASP.NET how to modify control id 'ContentPlaceHolder1'?

Tags: asp.net, tags

When I create a Gridview in ASP.NET, I set this control id "FactoryTable", but in browser html code, his id turn "ContentPlaceHolder1_FactoryTable"
Can I delete "ContentPlaceHolder1_" or modify for other name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the attribute

`ClientIDMode="Static"`

to the GridView markup.

---

Example:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtEcho2" runat="server" Width="65%" ClientIDMode="Static" />`

Example output:

`<input id="txtEcho2" style="width: 65%" name="ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$txtEcho2" />`

See here for the different modes:

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx